# Deleting Uptime Check

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've looking at the "Uptime Checks Overview" in Google Stackdriver, and I see "[Deleted GAEModule]", would like to get rid of it from the list but clicking "Delete" from the menu gives me "Cannot delete check [Deleted GAEModule]". Any way to get rid of this other than the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete an Uptime check if there is a Policy Alert associated with it.

So:

1. Delete the Policy alert here:
   https://app.google.stackdriver.com/policy-advanced
2. Delete the Uptime check

Comment: or filter them out of your policy